# How assigned TypedChoiceField as form class to model Field with choices?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-widget, django-models

I had `CharField with` `choices` in the model, but I need for this field render as `CheckboxSelectMultiple`, which returns list to a form class. With `TypedChoiceField` form class, which automatic assigned to `Field` with choices, it's not validate. I decided to change `form_class` in the field and written a new field with `TypedMultipleChoiceField` `form_class`, to validate list.

```
class MultipleTypedChoiceModelField(models.Field):
    def get_internal_type(self):
        return 'MultipleTypedChoiceModelField'

    def formfield(self, **kwargs):
        defaults =  {'form_class': TypedMultipleChoiceField, }
        defaults.update(kwargs)
        return super(MultipleTypedChoiceModelField, self).formfield(**defaults)
```

But it is have no effect. If I commented out the choices in the model field, the type is MultipleTypedChoiceModelField. So I believe that the form_class is appointed in appliance with a list of choices definition.

```
def formfield(self, **kwargs):
    if self._choices: # or self.choices:
        defaults =  {'form_class': TypedMultipleChoiceField, }
        defaults.update(kwargs)
    return super(MultipleTypedChoiceModelField, self).formfield(**defaults)
```

But it is have no effect too. **I have not found where is the assignment of `form_class`.** Maybe I have better way to change this behavior? *Adding an extra model with many to many relation I do not plan, because it is obviously unnecessary.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of the problem is that if you have something like this in your model:

```
myfield = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=MY_FIELD_CHOICES)
```

Django is going to assume that myfield holds just *one* choice, nut multiple choices.

Easiest way to implement this is to just have something like this in your model:

```
myfield = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

and then in your custom form:

```
myfield = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=MY_FIELD_CHOICES, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple())
```